# How to echo images based on data from database? (Mysql, Php)

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am doing some sort of online storefront and each item has a corresponding image in the database. i need to echo the image of that specific item, how do i do it?
This is what i've done, But it doesn't seem to work:

```
<?php
  $prebuy = "SELECT lot_image FROM lots WHERE  lot_id= '$lot_id'";
  $prebuyres = mysqli_query($mysqli, $prebuy) or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));
  $lot_name = mysqli_fetch_assoc($prebuyres);
?>
<img src="C:\\xampp\htdocs\storefront\img\<?php  echo ucwords($lot_name['lot_image']); ?>"
```

The image does not appear but there is no error either. What am i doing wrong? Please, help if you can.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you pastebin a var_dump on $lot_name?

Comment: Have you inspected the source using firebug or similar? Is the img generating a file not found error? Also, why are you using ucwords()?

Comment: @maltray how do i do that?

Comment: @StephenWidom not sure about ucwords i just read it somewhere i thought that was the right way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You missed enclosing img tag. try this way...and what about ucwords, to be sure first check result before using it.

```
 echo ucwords($lot_name['lot_image']); 

<img src="C:\\xampp\htdocs\storefront\img\<?=ucwords($lot_name['lot_image'])?>"/>
```

Edit:
       set you image source relative to your php script in server like

```
   <img src="img/<?=ucwords($lot_name['lot_image']);?>"/>
```

Comment: Is that image is present in your C:\\xampp\htdocs\storefront\img\Imagenane       path??

Comment: yes it is located inside the img folder specified in the directory.